# How to "soften" the edges of a polyline?

Tags: graphics, geometry, polygon

Given a line made up of several points, how do I make the line smoother/ curvier/ softer through adding intermediate points -- while keeping the original points completely intact and unmoved?

To illustrate, I want to go from the above to the below in this illustration:

[image]

Note how in the above picture, if we start at the bottom there will be a sharper right turn. In the bottom image however, this sharp right turn is made a bit "softer" by adding an intermediate point which is positioned in the middle of the two points, and using averages of the angles of the other lines. (Differently put, imagine the lines a race car would drive, as it couldn't abruptly change direction.) Note how, however, none of the original points was "touched", I just added more points.

Thanks!! For what it's worth, I'm implementing this using JavaScript and Canvas.

Comment: You could interpolate along as if it was a Bezier curve: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Comment: Just found a related thread (with no picked answer yet): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891740/drawing-smooth-lines-with-canvas

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following code found [elsewhere here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7058606/34170) does the job for me, in the specific context of JavaScript-Canvas which I'm using -- but please see Angus' answer for a more general approach:

```
var max = points.length;
context.beginPath();
var i = 0;
context.moveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
for (i = 1; i < max - 2; i++) {
    var xc = (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) * .5;
    var yc = (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) * .5;
    context.quadraticCurveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y, xc, yc);
}
context.quadraticCurveTo(points[max - 2].x, points[max - 2].y, points[max - 1].x,points[max - 1].y);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
```

Comment: What you're doing there is just creating a quadratic bezier curve based on your (control) vertices, also known as CV Curve.  If this works for you, feel free to accept your own answer. :]

Comment: It does work in my specific case, thanks again for your comments! OK, I will go ahead and mark this as answer then.

Answer (score 5):

with each edge (e1 & e2) adjacent to each 'middle' edge (me) do

- let X = 0.5 x length(me)
- find 2 cubic bezier control points by extending the adjacent edges by X (see algorithm below)
- get midpoint of cubic bezier (by applying formula below)
- insert new 'midpoint' between me's two coordinates.

[image: example]

```
FloatPoint ExtendLine(const FloatPoint A, const FloatPoint B, single distance)
{
  FloatPoint newB;
  float lenAB =  sqrt((A.x - B.x) * (A.x - B.x) + (A.y - B.y) * (A.y - B.y));
  newB.X = B.x - (B.x - A.x) / lenAB * distance;
  newB.Y = B.Y - (B.Y - A.Y) / lenAB * distance;
  return newB;
}
```

Edit: [Formula for Bezier Curve midpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54216695/359538): p(0.5) = 0.125(p0) + 0.375(p1) + 0.375(p2) + 0.125(p3)

Comment: Thanks so much for adding the code too! Could you please explain again what the distance parameter needs to be?

Comment: Looks like JavaScript-Canvas does have some native functionality that looks like it helps, I'm just reading through it: http://w3schools.com/html5/canvas_quadraticcurveto.asp and http://w3schools.com/html5/canvas_beziercurveto.asp

Comment: Another potentially relevant thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891740/drawing-smooth-lines-with-canvas

Comment: `distance` is arbitrary. A good starting value is half the length of the edge you want to smooth.

Comment: Sorry, in hospital and out of action. Yes, distance is arbitrary and depends on how prominent the smoothing you wish.